# Webpage not being displayed in webview & getting redirected to browser

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to implement basic webview. However, when I enter the url and click on a button to load it, I get a popup asking me to choose from a list of applications to load that webpage.The webpage then loads perfectly in the browser.I have added the INTERNET permission in the Manifest file. Please help me to spot the error or missing logic.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "WebViewActivity";
Button button1;
EditText et1;
String address;
WebView wv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            address=et1.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG,"url has been stored in address");
            wv1.loadUrl(address);
            Log.d(TAG,"url should now be loaded in webview");


        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set setWebViewClient listener:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false; 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

now replace this code with your code...

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String TAG = "WebViewActivity";
        Button button1;
        EditText et1;
        String address;
        WebView wv1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
            wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    address=et1.getText().toString();
                    Log.d(TAG,"url has been stored in address");
                    wv1.loadUrl(address);
                    Log.d(TAG,"url should now be loaded in webview");


                }
            });

        }

        private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
               view.loadUrl(url);
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

           }
       }
```